# If a function is discontinuous, why doesn't it contradict the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, riemann-integration

So for example, suppose $g(x) = \int_o^x F(t) dt$ where $$F(t) = 
\begin{cases}
t & 0 \leq t \leq 1 \\
t - 1 & 1 < t \leq 2
\end{cases}
$$

The function $g$ is not differentiable at 1. I am curious to why it doesn't contradict the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. Some thoughts and assistance

Comment: Because the ftc only claims to hold for continuous integrands

Comment: The standard version of the FTC requires that $F$ be continuous on $[0,2]$. But you have a discontinuity at $1$.

Comment: Why does a duck not contradict the statement that "dogs cannot fly"? Because ducks are not dogs. Likewise, the FTC part 2 is a statement about continuous functions; if your function is not continuous, the FTC does not even come to the party.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus states that *if* $f$ *is continuous*, then$$x\mapsto\int_a^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt$$is differentiable. And your function $F$ is *not* continuous.